# SFML Unresolved external symbol (LINKER FAIL)

Tags: c++, dll, linker, sfml

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event e;
        while (window.pollEvent(e))
        {
            if (e.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure, why my program doesn't work. I tried to write libraries in input in Linker settings, but still not working. Also I defined SFML_STATIC for preprocessor heading, however I'm not sure do I need this or not.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to my code working. Everything was explained above.

Comment: You need `SFML_STATIC` only if you are linking static libraries. Otherwise it just leads to linker errors.

Comment: @user7860670, seems true, but what do I need for my code to work?

Comment: You need to eliminate `SFML_STATIC`.

Comment: @user7860670, this doesn't help, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

perhaps run your program in both debug and release mode. then copy the bin/dll files over to those folders. also remove SFML_STATIC and you should be good to go, if youre using debug mode be sure to add -d to the linker input! hope this helps.

and also be sure youre using x86 version. you really shouldnt touch x64 unless you have some very specific apps you have to make.